# How to not commit confidential data but make it available for script?

Tags: security, heroku

I'm writing a slack bot, and I have a private token. I plan to deploy it on Heroku, so I can't add the file with the token to `.gitignore`. Is there a way to prevent exposing the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to handle this on Heroku is to use `heroku config:set SLACKTOKEN=your-token-here`. This makes an environment variable named `SLACKTOKEN` available to your app. With node.js, you'd read it via `process.env.SLACKTOKEN`.

For running locally, `heroku local` will read variables from a file called `.env`, so you should put the same variable there and use `.gitignore` to make sure it's not pushed to your repo.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables for details.